# Not able to run wiremock server from docker file in intellij

Tags: docker, intellij-idea, wiremock

I am new to docker.I was trying to create a wiremock for my pet project. I am able to run wiremock locally with command `java -jar wiremock-jre8-standalone-2.33.1.jar --port 8089 --verbose`

Now, I do wanna spin my wiremock server up from intellij, instead of terminal. What do I need to do for that? What configurations do I need inside my Dockerfile and docker-compose-wiremock.yml file.
Please any one guide me.

Comment: You should be able to run the exact same command in a docker image as long as you install all the correct dependencies.

Comment: See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-a-java-app-in-a-container.html#785c7f6a